# Move rows from one table to another liquibase

Tags: xml, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-sql

I need to drop one table, but before I need to move all the data that is in that table to another table with xml liquibase. I tried with `update` but it is giving ORA-00936: missing expression. Can someone help please ? What is the syntax / correct way to migrate one table to another row by row ?

Than k you.

Comment: add an example what did you tried

Answer (score 0):

What about sqlChange with insert from source table? Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30cc3/1) to test. Note it could take a lot of time if table is too big.

```xml
<changeSet id="id" author="you">
    <sql>insert into target_table select * from source_table</sql>
</changeSet>
```